# Getting "Error in DW script:" message with no details

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio

I have known good code (it's been implemented for days).

My runtime is 3.9.5
My Anypoint Studio version is 6.6.11

The error shows up on all transforms and is simply "**Error in DW script:**" with no further explanation. None of the dw scripts have been altered so it's clearly environmental, but I can't identify the issue.

Here is an example of one:

```
<dw:transform-message metadata:id="4bbf0f0a-d0fb-4018-972c-fa62138b3f60" doc:name="fail message">
                    <dw:input-variable mimeType="application/java" variableName="responseMessage"/>
                    <dw:input-variable mimeType="application/java" variableName="postMessage"/>
                    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0% output application/json
---
{
    statusCode: "403",
    statusMessage: flowVars.postMessage
}]]></dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>
```

Comment: Where do you see the error? In Studio error tab, Mule execution log, another place? When do you see it? At design time, execution time? Share the pom, or at least the dependencies of the project and Mule plugin. Are you sure Studio understands it is a Maven based project?

Comment: Really unclear... problem vanished. Not sure that I did anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a known issue in Studio 6. It should have been fixed in Studio 6.6.11 but it seems not fully fixed: https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/studio/anypoint-studio-6.6-with-3.9.5-runtime-update-site-11-release-notes#fixed-issues

Comment: Do you know of a work around? It comes back from time to time and it is very disruptive.

Comment: No. If you are interested open a support case with MuleSoft mentioning the link I shared. Although I would strongly recommend to start migrating to Mule 4/Studio 7 because [Mule 3/Studio 6 are going to end of life March 2024](https://www.mulesoft.com/legal/versioning-back-support-policy#support-matrix).